# Why is are unbiased statistics used more commonly than statistics with lower MSE?

Tags: variance, bias, unbiased-estimator, consistency

I understand the difference between consistency and bias; one converges as the sample size increases, and the other converges as the number of estimates increases, respectively.

But, I don't understand why people generally prefer the unbiased version of sample variance to estimate population variance.  Using simulation, it can be shown that a biased estimator of the population variance can have [lower MSE than an unbiased estimator](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/bias_consistency/).

So, why do we use the unbiased version of sample variance if the MSE can be higher?

Another question might be how to accurately estimate the MSE without using simulation, since a big component of MSE is Variance of the estimator, and simulation is often not possible since it requires knowing the true value of the parameter/estimand (in this case, the estimand is the poulation variance).

http://www.johndcook.com/blog/bias_consistency/

Answer (score 1):

This might sound like a pun, but it is really about bias - variance trade offs. Use the biased version, and you have less variance but bias. Use the unbiased one, and you have no bias but more variance.

I think another, perhaps less valid reason, is that many people - when the learn statistics, tend to think of unbiasedness as an (very) important property. Hence they pick this version.

I any case, if you wish to do inference you will most likely need to apply some form of asymptotic result - in this case both estimators should do the trick equally well (or bad, as some might put it). And the choice is less important.

Comment: This skips the question of why is unbiasedness taught or taken as a very important property. In some specific contexts, as in meta-analysis, I could see how unbiasedness might be more attractive as precision can be increased, but I do not see this as a general case.